# Deny access to the people and groups page office 365

Tags: office-365

My client is a bit paranoid and don't want people to visit the people and groups page. This page you can enter from :

```
site settings ==> Users and Permissions => People and groups
```

or :
Click on the arrow under your name at a office 365 site. and then click people and groups in the top navigation.

From this page people can see all groups and the permissions of these groups.
If they click on more (on the quicklaunch) they can even see all groups (even from other sites).

Is there a way to block users from the people and groups page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to block users form site settings, but not for the People and Group option only. You could of course hide the link with jQuery, but they would still have access to the page `https://siteCollectionURL/_layouts/15/groups.aspx` where they can see all groups.

Blocking users is done in these 3 steps:

1. On the Site Settings page, select **shared with** from the gear icon

[image]

2. Click **Advanced** on the modal dialogue

[image]

3. Remove access for every group and user except owners

[image]

Now only owners of the site will have access to the site settings page.